# Smart docker cleaning

Tags: docker

We are using docker to build and push images to repositories.

Is there a 'smart' way to clean/remove docker objects (images, layers, volumes etc.) but not remove cache files (we need to preserve cache so our builds takes as low time as possible)?

We are already:

- removing images that were pushed to repo (couse we do not need them on building machine) - `docker rmi <already_pushed_image>`

Is there something more we can do? We could also have scheduled job with `docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)`, but that would also remove cache from our builds?

Comment: Have you checked `docker system prune --help` ?

Comment: @ponsfrilus by default it removes cache so thats not very good for my situation :/